# Clear Cache of a Compiled ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, asp.net-3.5

I have various caches on my compiled website. However, I need to clear all these caches. Is there a way of doing this (without having to restart the server!)?

Thanks!
Curt

Answer (score 1):

What cache mechanism are you using?

One typical method would be to have a routine such as:

```
        foreach (DictionaryEntry objItem in Cache)
        {
            Cache.Remove(objItem.Key.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Where would this code be placed? The website is compiled so I have no access to the code-behind files. Cheers, Curt

Comment: Thats a problem then.  This would have to be code included in a form, code behind or similar that you could call from a web page or external service.